# Access parent data inside dynamic child component in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-components, viewchild

Code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-child-inside-parent-component

Code description :

I have dynamically created child components while clicking on a button in the parent component.I have passed a input from parent to child component(@Input) to keep track of the button click counter value.But when i delete from the child component and add again i get the counter value wrong.I have restricted the button click to 5 times.

Example scenario : I have clicked the button 5 times so the child is rendered 5 times in case if i delete any one of the child component out of 5 (say i delete event 5 ) and click add event button from parent again i get duplicate of event 5 ?Is there a way to update the counter value in child components ? Any help would be really appreciated.Kindly see the example which i created to understand,Thanks in advance.

Comment: going by what you say you want, shouldnt it create a duplicate of event 5?

Comment: You said what it does. But you didn't say what you wanted it to do. Besides, why aren't you just using ngFor to display your child components?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Yes if i delete event 1 and if i click add event button again i should get the missing event out of 5.So if i delete event 1 i i should get back what i deleted instead of the existing events.

Comment: use an array to store which events have components?

Comment: Use an array of 5 elements, initialized with events with a "hidden" flag, set to true. When you click "Add event", find the first hidden event, and set its hidden flag to false. Use ngFor to iterate over the 5 events, and use ngIf to only display an event if it's not hidden.

Comment: @JBNizet can you join me in chat for few minutes https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164161/smartgeekdiscussions

Comment: Nope, the room is frozen. Ask your question here.

Comment: @JBNizet updated with new chat room on the same comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your working app:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-child-inside-parent-component-fygtyr

The only change is in travellers.component.ts in addComponent method and declared a class variable. The logic is to keep a track of the counters being displayed and assign a new value to the component on addition.

Hope it helps!

Comment: it does adds the removed event but when i click the add event button again and again it just keeps adding but i restricted the event add click to 5 times.

Comment: @Melvin added that logic as well, check now.